# Return string from Main() with CSharpCodeProvider

Tags: c#, .net, return, program-entry-point, csharpcodeprovider

I'm trying to compile C# code(nothing too complex, just Main() ) using CSharpCodeProvider. This code returns a string, but I can't understand how to pass this value to my function. Is it possible?

```
public string Execute(List<String> code, List<String> _referencedAssemblies)
    {
        CompilerParameters cp = new CompilerParameters();
        for (int i = 0; i < _referencedAssemblies.Count; i++) {
            cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(_referencedAssemblies[i]);
        }

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < code.Count; i++) {
            sb.Append(code[i]);
        }


        CSharpCodeProvider provider = new CSharpCodeProvider();
        CompilerResults result = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(cp, sb.ToString());
```

Comment: If your code write this value to a file you able to get value.

Comment: How exactly does the code you're compiling look like?

Comment: @svick http://pastebin.com/DhZk1X20